# PyODBC - cursor record value rounding

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am working on a Python script (Python version 2.5.1 on Windows XP) that involves connecting to a Microsoft Access (.mdb) database to read values from a table. I'm getting some unexpected results with one record whereby the field of interest precision is getting rounded.

I know the Access table field of interest is a Double data type. But, the value that caused me to discover this in the table is 1107901035.43948. When I read the value in the Python code and print it out, it's showing 1107901035.44.

Is there a pyODBC connection parameter or other that must be set? I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/w/list)

Here's what my code looks like (the intention is to resolve unneeded records by identifying the record that has the greatest value for my field of interest):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + pGDB)
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()

tableList = []
for x in cursor.tables():
    val = str(x[2])
    if val[0:3] <> "MSy":
        if val[0:3] <> "GDB":
            if val[-5:] <> "Index":
                tableList.append(val)

for x in tableList:
    try:
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM %s" % (x)
        cursor.execute(SQL)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        counter = 0
        for row in rows:
            counter +=1

        if counter > 1:
            print "Site %s is a multipart basin" % (x)
            SQL = "SELECT MAX(Shape_Area) AS AREA FROM %s" % (x)
            cursor.execute(SQL)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            val = row.AREA
            print str(val)
            SQL = "DELETE * FROM %s WHERE Shape_Area < %s" % (x, val)
            cursor.execute(SQL)
```

thanks,
Tom

Comment: Yes I do, it returns 110790103543948.0

Answer (score 0):

Django uses the Jinja template, so you can use its round filer. It works as follows:

template.html

```
<p>{{ VALUE| round(2, 'floor') }}</p>
```

Check out Jinja's [documentation on topic](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.round)

The SQL round function can also do this job:

```
SQL = "SELECT ROUND(MAX(Shape_Area), 2) AS AREA FROM %s" % (x)
```